# Run python as root using cap_sys_admin capability linux

Tags: python, linux, privileges

I have the following capability of python2.7 (using getcap):

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 = cap_sys_admin+ep
```

I know that `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` is "CAP_SYS_ADMIN is a highly privileged access level and should generally be avoided as it is equivalent to root access level." (https://docs.bridgecrew.io/docs/bc_k8s_36)

It's mean that I can run as root using /usr/bin/python2.7?

So how actually I can get example root bash using `/usr/bin/python2.7`?

Answer (score 2):

Setting `cap_sys_admin` on `/usr/bin/python` means that python will be able to make any 'root' system call. This means that any one who runs python has the power to do things that normally only root can do. If someone (maliciously or accidentally) tries to do something dangwerous, they won't be stopped. Something as simple as the following could be catastrophic:

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('/')
```

In most cases if you need a script to run with elevated privileges it is better to use a user account that has these permissions, using `su` or `sudo`, rather than making a command always run without limits. That way you can focus on 'who' is allowed to do thingsm rather than 'what'.

Comment: hmm If I try something like read '/etc/shadow' using with open('/etc/shadow') as f:
    content = f.readlines() I got exception IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/shadow' so what I can run as root?